# Javascript canvas: Set own color for two different objects (squares)

Tags: javascript

I'm real frustrated with this problem. 
So, I have following simple code:

```
var canvas = document.getElementById('canvasField');
var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

function Square(x, y, sizeOfSide) {

    this.draw = function () {
        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.moveTo(x,y);
        ctx.lineTo(x + sizeOfSide, y);
        ctx.lineTo(x + sizeOfSide, y + sizeOfSide);
        ctx.lineTo(x, y + sizeOfSide);
        ctx.lineTo(x,y);
        ctx.closePath();
        ctx.stroke();
    }

    this.setColor = function (color) {
        ctx.fillStyle = color;
        ctx.fill();
    }
}
```

Square is my object. I can draw square and probably I can set fill-color for it. So next code works fine.

```
var square1 = new Square(100, 100, 100);
var square2 = new Square(250, 200, 100);
square1.draw();
square1.setColor('green');
square2.draw();
square2.setColor('yellow');
```

https://i.stack.imgur.com/gz50K.png

But If I change it to this:

```
var square1 = new Square(100, 100, 100);
var square2 = new Square(250, 200, 100);
square1.draw();
square2.draw();

square1.setColor('green');
square2.setColor('yellow');
```

it breaks down:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qeojl.png

It seems to me that I understand the reason. Two objects have the same context. And square2 sets color yellow for context and square1 loses his color. Maybe I am not right. I expected that they will be two independent objects and I'll be able to manipulate their conditions at any place in the code. I have no idea what to do next. Please help!

Comment: If you want to use like independent object try using library like [fabricjs](http://fabricjs.com/).  In your second code its not working because you created another path using `beginPath` and closed the prev one. so that fill color worked for second object not for the first one.

Comment: Yes. If I just remove lines beginPath and ClosePath two squares will be yellow. Can I fix it not using third-part libraty ?

Comment: [fill](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/fill) will fill the current path,

Comment: Call `this.draw()` also inside `setColor`

Comment: `ctx` has no `fillStyle`

Comment: @clabe45 check [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/fillStyle)

Comment: @Durga I see now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**DEMO**

```js
var canvas = document.getElementById('canvasField');
var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

function Square(x, y, sizeOfSide) {

    this.draw = function () {
        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.moveTo(x,y);
        ctx.lineTo(x + sizeOfSide, y);
        ctx.lineTo(x + sizeOfSide, y + sizeOfSide);
        ctx.lineTo(x, y + sizeOfSide);
        ctx.lineTo(x,y);
        ctx.closePath();
        ctx.stroke();
    }

    this.setColor = function (color) {
        this.draw();
        ctx.fillStyle = color;
        ctx.fill();
    }
}

//var square1 = new Square(100, 100, 100);
//var square2 = new Square(250, 200, 100);
//square1.draw();
//square1.setColor('green');
//square2.draw();
//square2.setColor('yellow');

var square1 = new Square(100, 100, 100);
var square2 = new Square(250, 200, 100);

//square1.draw();
//square2.draw();

square1.setColor('green');
square2.setColor('yellow');
```

```css
canvas {
 border : 2px dotted blue;
}
```

```html
<canvas id='canvasField' width=500 height=500></canvas>
```

Call the `draw` function of object inside `setColor` function. So it will draw the square first then will [fill](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/fill) it using given color.

Answer (score 0):

Most of time when you want to change something on a canvas, you have to draw it again. Your first block of code is good, if you want to change color of a square, use setColor then draw it again.